# Using rowlink on list items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap v3 in a project. I'm currently using Jasny which has the super nice [rowlink helper](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#rowlink). I would like to use this same type of functionality in my list element. Currently, I have the following code:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-info">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

How do I implement rowlink or something similar in behavior to rowlink on list items?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. The rowlink plugin helps to make the complete row clickable instead of only one column. But with a list, you only have one column.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-info">
  <li><a href="/i1">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/i1">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/i1">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to have the links just look more like normal text, set

```
.list-info a,
.list-info a:hover {
  color: inherit;
}
```